# How to geometrically interpret the forms $z^\top \Sigma^{-1} z$ and $x^\top\Sigma x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, covariance

For PSD $\Sigma$ ($\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}_+$), I am trying to gain some intuition about the difference between these two expressions.

### $z^\top \Sigma^{-1} z$

Where $z \sim N(0, \Sigma)$. I am quite comfortable with the expression $x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x$ as it usually shows up in things like Gaussians. I have the general intuition that this can be interpreted as,
$$
z^\top \Sigma^{-1} z = z^\top Q\Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}Q z = x^\top x
$$

Where $\Sigma = Q\Lambda Q$ is the eigendecomposition of $\Sigma$. If $x$ is correlated according to the covariance $\Sigma$ then $xQ\Lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ can be seen as decorrelating the dimensions of $x$ by rotating and scaling and thus returning the covariance ellipse back to a circle in the Euclidean basis and then taking the Euclidean distance

### $x^\top \Sigma x$

Where $x \sim N(0, I)$. I have more trouble understanding what is happening here geometrically because it seems like we are taking some Gaussian noise in the unit circle and then correlating is according to the covariance,

$$
x^\top \Sigma x = x^\top Q\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}Q x \ = z^\top z
$$

**Questions**

- If what I have derived so far is correct, why would one want to take the dot product of $z^\top z$? Can you describe any practical reason why this would be useful?
- Can you provide some examples of where and why this is used? (I have two which inspired this question [Bayesian Linear Regression - With Conjugate Priors Section (Equation 2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression) and this paper titled [Revisiting natural gradient for deep networks - equations 4 and 5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3584.pdf))
- Anything else interesting to say about these forms?

Comment: In your first link I can't find an equation (2). The equations (4) and (5) in the second link I can -for the life of me- not relate to your question.

Comment: equation 2 is not numbered in the wikipedia link, its just the second equation in that section which has the same general form ($x^\top \Sigma x$) as $(\beta - \hat{\beta})^\top \mathbf{XX}^\top (\beta - \hat{\beta})$. The second link equations 4-5 contain the term $\Delta \theta^\top \mathbf{F} \Delta \theta$ (and $\mathbf{F}$ is a positive semidefinite covariance matrix in the same form as my question). The point of my question is asking about the purpose of this general form which is basically the Mahalanobis distance in reverse.

Comment: The "form" $x^\top\Sigma x$ is used when we want to simulate a vector $z$ of Gaussians with desired covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Obviously, $z=\Lambda^\frac{1}{2}Qx$ does the job when $x$ are uncorrelated Gaussians. Alternatively you can use a Cholesky decomposition: $\Sigma=LL^\top$ and set $z=L^\top x$. The other form $z^\top\Sigma^{-1}z=x^\top x$ is obviously the inverse of the first form. Surely all of this has a geometric interpretation.